# Журналирование в Yii

Tags: yii

Есть проект на Yii 1. 
Достался от другого разработчика. 
Там в папке runtime хранятся логи, 5 файлов. 
Каждый по 1мб. 
Запись логов идет циклически, т.е. после того, как заполнится новый, старые удаляются.

Вопрос: Где отрегулировать количество данных файлов или их размер. Так как такого количества логов не хватает. 
В документации не смог найти эту информацию.

Comment: Неисключено, что в документации Вы этих сведений и не найдёте, т.к. логирование может быть написано специально под этот проект. Совет один: изучайте код проекта. Скорре всего ответ скрывается именно в нём.

Comment: в Yii уже есть хороший логгер, было бы странно писать свой просто ради того, что бы написать то, что уже написано. В этом же и есть смысл использования фреймворка - использовать готовые методы.

Comment: @Stalker, это всё верно. Только разработчики бывают, скажем так, разные и проекты после них остаются тоже разные.Да и не всегда функционал из коробки подходит под задачу. Поэтому всё может быть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Догадка будет "пальцем в небо", но скорее всего параметры будут где то в /protected/config/, там должено быть что то похожее на

```
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
```

там же должны описываться параметры maxFileSize=1024 и maxLogFile=5 их можно менять на свой вкус.

Документация по логгеру (там в самом начале описывается какими свойствами можно управлять логгером): 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute